# Remove XML node based on node value

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a little problem with my XML and PowerShell script.
I need remove a `Vlan` Item of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings> 
  <ARP>
    <ConfigVLAN>
      <Vlan>Vlan1</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan2</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan3</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan4$</Vlan>
    </ConfigVLAN>
  </ARP>
</Settings>
```

But I can't remove `<Vlan>Vlan4$</Vlan>` with the `RemoveChild` method....

```
$xml.Settings.ARP.configVLAN.SelectSingleNode("Vlan[text()=""$($selectedItem)""]").RemoveChild()
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `RemoveChild` method on the parent and pass the actual node you want to delete as parameter:

```
$selectedItem = 'Vlan4$'
$xmlFilePath = "Your_xml_file_path"

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlFilePath)
$nodeToRemove = $xml.Settings.ARP.configVLAN.SelectSingleNode("Vlan[text()=""$($selectedItem)""]")
$xml.Settings.ARP.ConfigVLAN.RemoveChild($nodeToRemove) | out-null
$xml.Save($xmlFilePath)
```